# Is there a way to set an object property to a relative time in the future in a Palantir Foundry Action?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-actions

I have an object type in my ontology that functions like a ticket/request system. As users view and respond to each ticket, I'd like there to be an action that represents a "deferral" of action. This action would make the following updates:

- Set the "Last Checked At" property to NOW
- Set the "Snoozed Until" property to NOW + 7 days

I was able to accomplish the first via the Action Rules UI, but I can't figure out the second one.  I tried a few things, like entering a static value, but what I'm looking for is probably more like a "relative time" field where I'd be able to enter "7 days from NOW". Is there a way to do it, or should I make this a function-backed action? Any help would be appreciated - let me know if I need to provide more details.

Edit on 04/13/2023: For my use-case, I wanted to use the value of "7 days from NOW" in a Workshop application. Ultimately, I decided to create a function-backed variable that I could then use in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you answered it yourself in the edit - but the answer is to indeed create a function-backed variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).